# The resistor's power consumption of 1 ohm in watts

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis, power-electronics, resistor-transistor-logic

I ran into a old-midterm exam question that calculate the one-ohm resistor's power consumption in the following diagram in watts? I need some solution or hints. I try to solve it but I think the answer is not mentioned in the following (a) to (d).

[image]

a)  0/8

b)  1/1

c) 2/6

d) 4/8

my last solution is:

KCL: 4+4Vx-j-Vx=j2Vx

1/2 * ( (1/3) / 1) = 0/65

Comment: Please post your development, so we can help you...

Comment: You won't learn if we do this for you first you need to workout the current through the resistor or the voltage across it then you can use \$ P = I^2R\$ or \$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} \$

Comment: Dear @MartinPetrei, i do last answer.

Comment: Dear @WarrenHill, i know it but i couldn't solve it.

Comment: Note that the last calculation is wrong: 1/2*1/3=1/6

Comment: Dear @clabacchio, would you please add more detail as a solution?

Comment: I cna't now, but you could get more help if you showed better your process. For instance, explain how you got your calculations.

Comment: You can do this in two parts.  First write down the loop equation for the cosine, cap and R.  Find the current in the R. Then the same for the sine, L and R.  Now add the currents keeping care to get all the phases correct.

Comment: @chabarchio 1/2*((1/3)/1) is 1/2 * 3/1 or 2/3.  Also, a 1Farad 1V capacitor would be the size of a railroad car. Don't believe me, my brother in law built one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do with your equations. Your variable names make no sense.

The key to doing AC circuit analysis is to convert the capacitor and inductor to reactances in the frequency domain. I'll get you started. Your frequency is 2 radians per second (that's the 2 in cos(2t)). This means:

$$X_C = \frac{1}{j \omega C} = -j\frac12 = \frac12 \angle -90^\circ \ \Omega$$
$$X_L = j \omega L = j2 = 2 \angle 90^\circ \ \Omega$$

You also need to deal with the phase of the voltage sources as referenced to a cosine:

$$Left: 1 \angle 180^\circ \ V$$
$$Right: 1 \angle -90^\circ \ V$$

I'll let you solve the problem from there.

Answer (score 0):

How about this as a hint. 
AC passes through **__ but is blocked by __**

A. an inductor
B. a capacitor

Then you know what about the solution?

Comment: it dose not help me.

Comment: Dear @Ken, would u please complete your answer?

Comment: It's B. AC is blocked by a capacitor